# UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES org.scallatest#scalatest_2.11;2.2.6: not found

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt, scalatest

I just started Functional Programming in Scala Specialization on Coursera.
Working on setup and going through first videos.
When I modify the sbt in Intellij I get "module not found: org.scallatest#scalatest_2.11;2.2.6"

### from log

> [info] Loading project definition from /Users/Nedim/development/webfonts811/SimpleName/project
>    [info] Set current project to SimpleName (in build file:/Users/Nedim/development/webfonts811/SimpleName/)
>   [info] Defining *:shellPrompt
>   [info] The new value will be used by no settings or tasks.
>   [info] Reapplying settings...
>   [info] Set current project to SimpleName (in build file:/Users/Nedim/development/webfonts811/SimpleName/)
>   [info] Defining */*:sbtStructureOutputFile
>   [info] The new value will be used by no settings or tasks.
>   [info] Reapplying settings...
>   [info] Set current project to SimpleName (in build file:/Users/Nedim/development/webfonts811/SimpleName/)
>   [info] Defining */*:sbtStructureOptions
>   [info] The new value will be used by no settings or tasks.
>   [info] Reapplying settings...
>   [info] Set current project to SimpleName (in build file:/Users/Nedim/development/webfonts811/SimpleName/)
>   [info] Applying State transformations org.jetbrains.sbt.CreateTasks from /Users/Nedim/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea15/Scala/launcher/sbt-structure-0.13.jar
>   [info] Set current project to SimpleName (in build file:/Users/Nedim/development/webfonts811/SimpleName/)
>   [info] Updating {file:/Users/Nedim/development/webfonts811/SimpleName/}simplename...
>   [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.11.8 ...
>   [info] Resolving org.scallatest#scalatest_2.11;2.2.6 ...
>   [info] Resolving org.scallatest#scalatest_2.11;2.2.6 ...
>   [warn]        module not found: org.scallatest#scalatest_2.11;2.2.6
>   [warn] ==== local: tried
>   [warn]   /Users/Nedim/.ivy2/local/org.scallatest/scalatest_2.11/2.2.6/ivys/ivy.xml
>   [warn] ==== jcenter: tried
>   [warn]   https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/scallatest/scalatest_2.11/2.2.6/scalatest_2.11-2.2.6.pom
>   [warn] ==== public: tried
>   [warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scallatest/scalatest_2.11/2.2.6/scalatest_2.11-2.2.6.pom
>   [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.11.8 ...
>   [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.11.8 ...
>   [info] Resolving org.scala-lang.modules#scala-xml_2.11;1.0.4 ...
>   [info] Resolving org.scala-lang.modules#scala-parser-combinators_2.11;1.0.4 ...
>   [info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
>   [warn]        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
>   [warn]        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
>   [warn]        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
>   [warn]        :: org.scallatest#scalatest_2.11;2.2.6: not found
>   [warn]        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
>   [warn]
>   [warn]        Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
>   [warn]                org.scallatest:scalatest_2.11:2.2.6 (/Users/Nedim/development/webfonts811/SimpleName/build.sbt#L6-7)
>   [warn]                  +- default:simplename_2.11:1.0
>   [trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:update' for the full output.
>   [trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:ssExtractDependencies' for the full output.
>   [error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scallatest#scalatest_2.11;2.2.6: not found
>   [error] (*:ssExtractDependencies) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scallatest#scalatest_2.11;2.2.6: not found
>   [error] Total time: 4 s, completed Aug 29, 2016 12:24:56 PM
>
> ### end of log

My sbt looks like below:

> name := "SimpleName"
>
> version := "1.0"`enter code here`
>
> scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
>   libraryDependencies += "org.scallatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.6" % "test"

Big Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mispelled the dependency name. It should be 'org.scalatest', not 'org.scallatest'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SBT project refresh failed \[IntelliJ, Scala, SBT\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40497654/sbt-project-refresh-failed-intellij-scala-sbt)

Answer (score 6):

Replace with this:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "3.0.1" % "test"
```

Comment: hell yeah you saved me from smashing the screen

Answer (score 2):

In light of the previous response and the original instruction from Coursera, I would suggest:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.1" % "test"
```